# Add User-Defined REST Interface Version to WADL

Tags: rest, version, cxf, wadl

The URI `foo/bar/?_wadl` allows me to list the services provided by a REST interface.

Is there a way (using annotation or otherwise) to have this XML view display a user-defined version number so that I know the version of the REST interface I'm looking at?

Comment: It must be possible but the exact way depends on how the WADL is returned. Are you using some framework?

Comment: @Tom, we're using Apache CXF, thanks.

Comment: How and where is the version number defined?

Comment: It's not, that's what I want to be able to do.  I want to be able to define it in my REST class such that hitting ?_wadl will display this value so I can tell at a glance what the version is without having to look at the source code.